# Erro ao conectar Postgres a api em NodeJS Sequelize

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, postgresql

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer uma migration usando o Postgres como Banco de Dados e utilizando o Sequelize. Ao dar npx sequelize db:migration, o terminal me retorna o erro:

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.19.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.16.1]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
/home/pc/food_ecomerce_api/node_modules/pg/lib/sasl.js:24
throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')
^

Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
at Object.continueSession

Segue o código do database.js na pasta config:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  },
  dialectOptions: {

  },
  timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
};
```

e o código da migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('users', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password_hash: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    created_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }),
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Seu arquivo *.env* existe e está configurado corretamente com as variáveis necessárias? Poderia colocar um console.log(process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD) para validar a senha do database.

Uma pessoa teve um problema parecido [nesse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878173/scram-server-first-message-client-password-must-be-a-string).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).